# Remove Primary Key constraint from a column

Tags: sql-server

How to remove primary key constraint from column?

I have table `t_data_dnefrc` table. In that I have `AccountNbr` column which is primary key. I want to remove Primary key constraint for that column.

Comment: What sort of database are you using? Microsoft SQL Server I guess?

Answer (score 2):

You need to drop the constraint, the name of which can be found in the Keys folder of the table in SQL Management Studio.

```
ALTER TABLE t_data_dnefrc
DROP CONSTRAINT constraintName;
```

Comment: "...the name of which can be found in the Keys folder of the table in SQL Management Studio".  Expand the table, then expand the Keys folder.  It's the yellow one...

Comment: i did nt find any name. Its Key sysmbol in yellow.

Comment: Did you refresh the list of keys?

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is mysql way - check Marcus's answer for the correct answer to OP's question.

```
ALTER TABLE t_data_dnefrc DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: oops - Thanks for that. Added a note to my post and +1ed you.